# Sentence dictionary in Azure cognitive services

Tags: translation, azure-cognitive-services

I'm having trouble to find the right way to create sentence dictionary using new portal
There is still a way to create one in legacy portal, but no clear examples. Also I'm curious if sentences would take into account grammar. I want to create some translations fron English to Polish which has quite complex grammar and depending on grammatical case and context different output is expected.

Answer (score 1):

We can you the translator dictionary from the new portal too. But we need to take the keys generated from the new portal to custom language translator portal. Let’s walk through the solution.

**Part 1: Language translation using Azure portal. Inbuild grammar (not complete)**

1. Go to azure portal and search for a translator

[image]

2. Fill in the details according to the subscription

[image]

[image]

[image]

The above block will convert the English language into Polish according to the requirement. Below is the python code generated for translation. Fill in the details required according to the subscription.

```
 import requests, uuid, json

# Add your key and endpoint
key = "<your-translator-key>"
endpoint = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com"

# location, also known as region.
# required if you're using a multi-service or regional (not global) resource. It can be found in the Azure portal on the Keys and Endpoint page.
location = "<YOUR-RESOURCE-LOCATION>"

path = '/translate'
constructed_url = endpoint + path

params = {
    'api-version': '3.0',
    'from': 'en',
    'to': ['fr', 'zu']
}

headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key,
    # location required if you're using a multi-service or regional (not global) resource.
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region': location,
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-ClientTraceId': str(uuid.uuid4())
}

# You can pass more than one object in body.
body = [{
    'text': 'I would really like to drive your car around the block a few times!'
}]

request = requests.post(constructed_url, params=params, headers=headers, json=body)
response = request.json()

print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

Get the keys before going to part 2

[image]

**Part 2: To add sentence dictionary. Use the custom translator services studio**

https://language.cognitive.azure.com/home -> Check into this link

[image]

[image]

[image]

This will create a project where we can choose the language to convert and start the translation with sentence dictionary. By default, sentence dictionary is application in new language translation.